# AJAX request causes change function unbind

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to implement simple functionality to allow users to save their message text as template to be used in the future.

php:

```
  echo '<div id="container">';
    $sql = ("SELECT template_id, template_text, template_name, member_id FROM message_templates
            WHERE member_id = {$member_id}");
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $confName = get_conference_name($confID);
    $confName = formatText_safe($confName);
    echo "<label>" . $lang['my_template'] . "</label><select id='tempchoose' name='templates'>";
    if ($num_rows == 0) {
        echo '<option value=""> ' . $lang['no_saved'] . '</option>';
    } else {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
            //$template_id = mysql_result($result, $i, 0);
            $temp_text = mysql_result($result, $i, 1);
            $temp_name = mysql_result($result, $i, 2);
            echo '<option value="' . $temp_text . '">' . $temp_name . '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo "</select></div>"; 
    echo '<input id="send" name="Message" value="send" disabled="disabled" type="submit" />
<input id="temp" name="temp" type="button" value="save as template" />"
<textarea style="width: 99%;" id="textarea" name="TextBox" rows="8" disabled="disabled" type="text" value=""/></textarea>';
```

javascript:

```
$("#temp").bind("click", function(){
            name=prompt("template name?");
            temp_text = $("#textarea").val();
        if (name!=null && name!="" && name!="null") {
            $.ajax ({
                data: {temp_text:temp_text, name:name},
                type: 'POST',
                url:  'save_template.php',
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response == "1") {
                        alert("template saved successfully");
                    } else {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("invalid template name");
        }
         $.ajax ({
                url:  'update_templates.php',
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#container").html(response);
                }
            });
    });
 $("select").change(function () {
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            $("#textarea").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#send").removeAttr("disabled");
              });
          $("#textarea").val($(this).val());
        })
        .trigger('change');
```

update_temp.php

```
$sql = ("SELECT template_id, template_text, template_name, member_id FROM message_templates
        WHERE member_id = {$member_id}");
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$confName = get_conference_name($confID);
$confName = formatText_safe($confName);
echo "<label>".$lang['my_template']."</label><select id='tempchoose' name='templates'>";
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<option value=""> '.$lang['no_saved'].'</option>';
} else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
        //$template_id = mysql_result($result, $i, 0);
        $temp_text = mysql_result($result, $i, 1);
        $temp_name = mysql_result($result, $i, 2);
        echo '<option value="' . $temp_text . '">' . $temp_name . '</option>';
    }
}
echo "</select>";
```

the last ajax request in `#temp` click function is used to updated the droplist with the newly created template, the problem is that when i click save template; ajax request is performed successfully and droplist is updated, however something wired happen which is that the change function of select is not working anymore! anyone knows where's the problem?

Comment: You changed the actual `<select>` element when you over-wrote it, and it no longer has the function bound to it because it is a whole new element with a whole new associated object on the DOM. The *best* way to solve the problem would be to load the new `<option>`s and re-build the existing `<select>` element's children, but the *easy* (read: *quick and dirty*) fix is to just bind the change handler again by running the last statement again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ajax will inject new elements to your DOM and those elements don't know about the binding you already defined.

**Solution** : use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Change

```
$("select").change(function () {
```

to

```
$(document).on("change","select", function(){
```

jQuery on is available from **1.7+** version onwards, if you are using a previous version of jQuery, consider using `delegate`.

Comment: You're dealing with the wrong element there (it is the select with its change event that he is changing) but aside from that the principal is sound.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rewriting the select with Ajax you should use .delegate() rather than simply .change, like:

```
$("someSelector").delegate("select", "change", function() {
 // do stuff...
});
```

where someSelector is an element that contains your select.

Comment: I agree with @Shyju that .on is better if you are using a current version of jQUery

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you have replaced the drop down inside of container, which will unhook all of the events on the drop down. The solution would be to modify the code as below:

```
         $.ajax ({
            url:  'update_templates.php',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#container").html(response);
                $("#container select").change(
                   // your drop down change functionality here //
                );
            }
        });
```

What this is doing is saying, "After the drop down has been refreshed, also refresh the event."

I hope this helps.